# SQL query help in where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, mysql

```
string sql1 = "select  jname, jcode 

from heardt,judge,main 

where heardt.jud1 = judge.jcode and main.fil_no=heardt.fil_no and ..

 main.fil_no= ";
```

I have a form in which user enters a `reg_no` on entering `reg_no` only name and address is displayed, in the same table there is `fil_no` which i want to be used in my above query to link to another table.

how can i specify it in my above query,in the third AND condition? please guide me.

Comment: I wish I could communicate with you in your native language.

Comment: And besides the poor English and poor explanation: in your previous question you asked how to do it without a `JOIN`. But you really *should* use a `JOIN`. There is no magical trick which makes your queries faster if you don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about JOINing tables I believe? Joins are very simple and are written as thus :-

SELECT t1.column1,t1,column2,t2.column1,t2.column2
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.key1 = t2.key1
WHERE .....

You can join as many tables as you require and have multiple JOIN types.
See more here :-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472.aspx